# fixed floating elements inside table cell on mobile

Tags: javascript, css, mobile-safari, css-position, reactjs

I am using react JS to design a page where I need some of the elements to stick to the top if they are going to be scrolled off the screen. I have been doing this using `position:fixed`, and it works perfectly on desktop chrome, safari, and firefox. However, when I test it on mobile safari, the fixed elements continue to scroll with the rest of the page. I have been doing some reading and it looks like support for `position:fixed` is spotty at best on mobile. Does anyone have any suggestions?

The render function of my sticky elements looks like this. `this.props.fixed` is a boolean representing whether or not the element should be stuck to the top of the screen `this.props.boxSize` is the number of pixels taken up by the elements that have stuck before this one (so that multiple sticky elements don't overlap). I know for certain that both of these two values are correct.

```
render: function(){
        var divStyle = {};
        var className = this.props.className + ' sticky';
        if(this.props.fixed){
            divStyle = {
                position: 'fixed',
                top: this.props.boxSize + 'px',
                background: '#ffffff',
                width: '100%',
                zIndex: 999999,
            };
            className = className + " fixed";
        }

        return(
            <div style={divStyle} className={className}>
                {this.props.children}
            </div>
            );
    }
```

I have also tried `position:absolute` instead of `position:fixed` and got the same result (works on desktop, scrolls with the content on mobile).

The really tricky part is that all of this is taking place inside of a table cell. I believe that that is what is causing the problem, but getting rid of the table cell is not an option. The less file for the parent element looks like this:

```
.scrollable {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  border-collapse: collapse;

  & > tbody > tr > td {
    padding: 0;
  }

  & > tbody > .content > td {
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
  }

  & > tbody > .content > td > div {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 1px 0;
    position: absolute;
    overflow-y: auto;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
    display: inline-block;
    left: 0%;
    top: 0;
  }
}
```

the content with fixed elements that I am trying to create lives inside of that tbody

Comment: what does the parent div of said div look like css-wise?

Comment: Thanks @theClap I have edited my question to include more relevant info